# jQuery subtracts css property value when i fetch it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing a very ilogical and odd problem here.

I have defined the width, height and other properties in a seperate CSS file. Now I wan these values on the run time to manipulate them and make my application dynamic.

But when I fetch this value using `jQuery`, it subtracts one or two from the value.

For example, the width of an element defined in the `CSS` is 450px, now when I fetch it in `jQuery` using

```
$('.programeSectionBox').width();
```

It will give me 449px. This thing is also happening with height and margin parameters too.

Can somebody please tell me whats happening here, I am badly `struct` in this problem .

---

Thanx for all the replies. I have checked the outerWidth() solution but its not working, giving the same issue.

Actually I am creating an application for Samsung Smart TV, they are offering two resolutions 960x540 and 1280x720. For 960x540 everything is working great, but when it comes to 1280x720, the problem is occuring which I have mentioned.

In my application I am using one javascript file and two different CSS files for the two resolutions, the applications checks that on which TV resolution its working and then loads the respective CSS. I cant hardcode the values in JavaScript file because I want to keep it dynamic, if I will hardcode the values, it will obviously work for one resolution.

So if anybody have any other solution, it will be great.

Thanx

Comment: could you please post your code. jsfiddle would be much better to help you out.

Comment: The browser's box model might be a key. Have you tried with different browsers?

Comment: what happens if you call $(".whatever").css("width");

Answer (score 1):

Try using outerWidth and see if that works for you:

```
jQuery("#myElement").outerWidth();
```

More on outerWidth:

http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

Comment: thanx alot Billy for trying to help, but its not working either.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `parseInt` to the value you get it.

After that you will get integer value then you can perform any operation on it.

```
console.log(​parseInt('445px')​​);​
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UPwGH/)**

Comment: How is that in any way relevant?

Comment: @Paystey This will convert the value to integer and then he can perform the any math operation. Which is not possible on string.

Comment: He is asking a totally different question. -1 for not even reading the 10 lines the OP has written.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is happening with several computed values (not only width/height), I would guess that **your browser is zoomed**. In your case it is probably zoomed out one step, since you seem to be getting lower values than the ones you set via CSS.

Try this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zsygt/

When the browser zoom is reset to it’s default value (100%), it should print `448`. But when I zoom in one step in Chrome, it prints `449`.